# Java Reflection with Abstract classes

Tags: java, reflection, jaxb, abstract-class, anonymous-class

JAXB has generated a class with a setter method that takes an abstract class as its parameter:

`setAppointmentDate(AvailableDates)`

I understand that I cannot instantiate abstract classes, so in order to create an `AvailableDates` object to pass to the method, I've created an anonymous subclass of `AvailableDates` (which at the same time instantiates it). This works and gives me expected results. However, to create the anonymous subclass, I've hard coded the name of the abstract class:

```
AvailableDates anonymous = new AvailableDates() {};
```

I now need to make this dynamic as the name of the class `AvailableDates` will be passed in as a parameter. I started
to use reflection for this:

```
String className = "AvailableDates";
Class abstractClass = Class.forName(className);
```

I now need to create an anonymous class from this but can't see how I can. The best I can see
is:

```
Object dates = abstractClass.newInstance();
```

This will obviously fail as you can't create an instance of an abstract class. I saw [Is it possible to create an anonymous class while using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100035/is-it-possible-to-create-an-anonymous-class-while-using-reflection) and if I understand correctly, it sounds like I can't use reflection with anonymous classes. Can anyone add more advice - is there another way round this especially in the context of JAXB?

Comment: Do not instantiate an abstract class. First question: why does the nasty evil JAXB expect for an abstract class?

Comment: An anonymous class can only be created with a constructor, which you don't have when using reflection.

Comment: @Dávid Horvath, I'm not sure why the parameter is an abstract class. I just let Eclipse create the JAXB classes from the XSD and this was the result.

Comment: @Bubletan, doesn't sound too good :( Do you know if there is another way other than using an anonymous class? I will still need to use reflection with an abstract class.

Comment: @DávidHorváth - JAXB like any other bit of software expects a concrete subclass as the value, where the property is an abstract class.

Comment: Of course. But must to check why the type is this (learn how to use the generated result of JAXB).

Answer (score 1):

### Where Did the Abstract Class Come From?

JAXB would generate an abstract class to correspond to an abstract complex type in the XML Schema.  In the example below the complex type `contactInfo` would correspond to an abstract class called `ContactInfo`, also the generated class `Customer` would have a property of this type.

```xml
<xs:schema 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/foo"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/foo">

    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="contactInfo" type="contactInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="contactInfo" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="address">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="contactInfo">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="phoneNumber">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="contactInfo">
                <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

### How to Set a Property that is an Abstract Type

For a property of this type you set the value to be one of the concrete subclasses.

```
    Address address = new Address();
    customer.setContactInfo(address);
```

Or

```
    PhoneNumber phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
    customer.setContactInfo(phoneNumber);
```

### How to Decide Which Subclass to Use?

> How do decide which of the concrete subclasses to use?

There isn't really an automated way to do this, you need to make a specific choice based on the data you are trying to represent. In the example above if you want the customer to be contacted by mail you set an instance of `Address` otherwise you set an instance of `PhoneNumber`.

---

### UPDATE

> I did try using one of the concrete subclasses and it works like you
>   said. The downside is that these concrete subclasses are not really
>   related to the setter method that I'm using. An example I can think of
>   is setAppointmentDate(StaffLeaveDates). Here StaffLeaveDates extends
>   AvailableDates as a concrete subclass but is not really anything to do
>   with an appointment date but it still works. Do you think this is the
>   best I can do? I'm just thinking that it could look confusing.

JAXB is going to enable you to create any XML document that is compatible with your XML Schema.  As far as it is concerned you told it (via the XML Schema) to allow any type that extends `AvailableDates` so it will happily accept `StaffLeaveDates`.  You can try and change your XML Schema so it is more restrictive (see example below).

**XML Schema**

Below is an updated version of the XML Schema that introduces a new subtype of `contactInfo` called `emailAddress` that I don't want to ever be used as a value on the `contactInfo` property on `customer`.  So I have changed `customer` to have a choice between `address` and `phoneNumber`.

```xml
<xs:schema 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/foo"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/foo">

    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="address" type="address"/>
                <xs:element name="phoneNumber" type="phoneNumber"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="contactInfo" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="address">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="contactInfo">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="phoneNumber">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="contactInfo">
                <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="emailAddress">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="contactInfo">
                <xs:attribute name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**Generated Model**

Now my `Customer` class can hold onto an `Address` or `PhoneNumber` (or both unfortuately), but not an `EmailAddress`.  Whatever property is null won't be marshalled to XML.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    protected Address address;
    protected PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
```

Comment: thanks Blaise - is there a glimmer of hope here? How do decide which of the concrete subclasses to use?

Comment: @user3572079 - I have updated my answer with some additional information.

Comment: Thank you Blaise for your updated answer - appreciate the detail. I did try using one of the concrete subclasses and it works like you said. The downside is that these concrete subclasses are not really related to the setter method that I'm using. An example I can think of is `setAppointmentDate(StaffLeaveDates)`. Here `StaffLeaveDates` extends `AvailableDates` as a concrete subclass but is not really anything to do with an appointment date but it still works. Do you think this is the best I can do? I'm just thinking that it could look confusing.

Comment: @user3572079 - I have updated my answer with some information that should help.